# how to use text-autospace declaration in html

Tags: html, css

here is my code:

```css
    p {
    
      text-auto space: ???
    }
```

```html
     <p style="  text-auto space: ???">     
      $student['first name']
     
     <p/>
```

make html page insert spaces automatically i want to know the usage of auto space in html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you meant was `text-autospace`. It is used to specify the spacing between different language characters, lets say when you write in English and Chinese in the same paragraph. It is also important to note that not all browsers support this, from what I understand only Internet Explorer supports the use of `text-autospace`

Here are the possible values you can put for `text-autospace`:

> **ideograph-alpha:** Inserts extra spaces between ideographic and non-ideographic (Latin-based, Cyrillic, Greek, Arabic, or Hebrew) text.
>
> **ideograph-numeric:** Inserts extra spaces between ideographic text and numeric characters.
>
> **ideograph-parenthesis:** Inserts extra spaces between normal (non-wide) parentheses and ideographs.
>
> **ideograph-space:** Extends the width of the space character when it is adjacent to ideographs.
>
> **none:**  No extra space is added.

Here's and example code to help illustrate its use

```
    <head>
    <style>
        .spaceNone {
            text-autospace: none;
        }
        .spaceIdeoNum {
            text-autospace: ideograph-numeric;
        }
        .spaceIdeoAlpha {
            text-autospace: ideograph-alpha;
        }
        .spaceIdeoSpace {
            text-autospace: ideograph-space;
        }
        .spaceIdeoParen {
            text-autospace: ideograph-parenthesis;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Autospace none: </div>
    <p class="spaceNone">1一 2二 3三 4四 5五 6六 7七 8八 9九 10十</p>
    <br />
    <div>Autospace ideograph-numeric: </div>
    <p class="spaceIdeoNum">1一 2二 3三 4四 5五 6六 7七 8八 9九 10十</p>
</body>
```

**[note]** You might not be able to see the effects unless you load it on Internet Explorer. Hope this helped!